# Linking to system python gives 'binary is not an allowed client' error

Tags: python, xcode, macos-monterey

I have just updated my Macbook to Monterey and installed XCode 13. I'm now seeing errors when trying to link my code - for example one library needs to link to the system python2.7, but gives the error:

> Keiths-MacBook-Pro:libcdb keith$ make rm -f libcdb.1.0.0.dylib
> libcdb.dylib libcdb.1.dylib libcdb.1.0.dylib
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
> -stdlib=libc++ -headerpad_max_install_names  -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk
> -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/../Frameworks -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Qt-5.15.7/lib -single_module -dynamiclib -compatibility_version    1.0 -current_version    1.0.0 -install_name libcdb.1.dylib -o libcdb.1.0.0.dylib release/db.o release/KDTree.o release/db_Wlist.o release/db_VSeg.o
> release/db_View.o release/db_ViaInst.o release/db_ViaGen.o
> release/db_Via.o release/db_Vertex.o release/db_Vector.o
> release/db_Utils.o release/db_Trapezoid.o release/db_Transform64.o
> release/db_Transform.o release/db_Techfile.o release/db_Style.o
> release/db_Signal.o release/db_Shape.o release/db_SegParam.o
> release/db_Segment.o release/db_Rectangle.o release/db_Rect.o
> release/db_QTree.o release/db_Property.o release/db_Polygon.o
> release/db_PointList.o release/db_Point.o release/db_Pin.o
> release/db_Path.o release/db_ObjList.o release/db_Obj.o
> release/db_Net.o release/db_Mst.o release/db_Mpp.o release/db_Lpp.o
> release/db_Line.o release/db_Library.o release/db_Layer.o
> release/db_Label.o release/db_InstPin.o release/db_Inst.o
> release/db_HVTree.o release/db_HSeg.o release/db_HierObj.o
> release/db_Group.o release/db_Ellipse.o release/db_Edge.o
> release/db_CellView.o release/db_Cell.o release/db_Array.o
> release/db_Arc.o  -F/usr/local/Qt-5.15.7/lib -L../libcpp/release -lcpp
> -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config
> -lpython2.7 -framework QtWidgets -framework QtGui -framework AppKit -framework Metal -framework QtNetwork -framework QtCore -framework DiskArbitration -framework IOKit -framework OpenGL -framework AGL
> ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an
> allowed client of
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.tbd
> for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: ***
> [release/libcdb.1.0.0.dylib] Error 1

Given that I have recompiled (successfully) the Qt libs and the code for this library, why is it giving me this 'your binary is not an allowed client' error?

As far as I can see the python2.7 paths have not changed, so the error is baffling.

Comment: There are a lot of results when you google this error. Please indicate what you've already looked up and tried so we don't waste our time giving you solutions that you know won't work. If you have not done such research, you need to before posting here.

Comment: I have indeed looked at the google results. They all seem to be along the lines of the library linked to is incorrect/wrong version etc. In this case, it's the system Python lib - and it worked fine before updating to Montery/Xcode 13.

Comment: Some more investigation and it seems that the Python.tdb file in XCode 12 lists the 'allowed clients' for libpython2.7. I'm guessing that Apple don't want you to link to Python2 as of this version of the SDK.

Comment: And a bit more work shows that if I edit the Python.tdb file in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current and add my library name 'cdb' then it links!

Answer (score 0):

So the quick and diirty fix is to edit the Python.tdb file that is located at:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python.tdb

And add your library/executable targets to the clients list.

Of course, there is a reason Apple are doing this - python2 is deprecated and sooner or later they will drop it. But until they do, this works.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was to drop the Python2 framework and link with the framework provided by my version of Python3 installed via Brew.

Locate your installation of Python3 by using this command in Terminal: `ls -la $(which python3)`.
The framework is in the "Frameworks" folder located one level above "bin", for example: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks

Once your have the location of the Python3 framework, add it as a framework in your XCode project.
In the Build Settings, don't forget to add:

- the Frameworks folder location in **Framework Search Path** (e.g. "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks")
- the framework's Headers folder in **Header Search Path** (e.g. "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers")

Some functions changed in version 3 so you'll need to update some of your Python function calls.

Comment: Apple ship Python 2.7 only even on Monterey - sure you can use something like Brew to install Python3, but that is not the system default.